# get '_id' row without cursor in SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android

Im lookink for get the _id "max" of my table (db : SQLiteDatabase) without use cursor. 
I mean :

I must delete all element of my table in my app, and after I add a new element...Before this new add, I would like know what is the _id max of my "empty" table.

How do that ? It's possible ? I search a method in SQLiteDatabase API, but I don't find my solution..

Thx for help =) (and sorry for my poor english ^^)

Answer (score 0):

for get max num of rows in table you can use:

```
public long count() {
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,'tablename');
}
```

Comment: hmmm its not I want, I apologize if I wasn't clear.
I don't want the number of row, I want the _id max, I mean : 
I have 3 rows in my table (_id 0, _id 1, _id 2), next I delete all rows. Now, I want know if it's possible to get the last _id although my table is empty.

After , when I add a new row (so my table have one element now), the _id is 3. So, before adding this row, can I get the _id max ?